# Invalid cors request in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, graphql, graphql-java

I am running a spring boot application in conjunction with graphql and jwt token. Currently when I am trying to hit one of the endpoints I am getting 'Invalid Cors Request'. Below is the code of config and filter file.
Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected  void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**", "/graphql", "/graphiql", "/graphql/**", "/graphiql/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Filter file:

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(authorizationHeader==null)
            throw new ServletException();

        String token = null;
        String userName = null;

        if (authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            userName = jwtUtil.extractUsername(token);
        }
        else
            throw new ServletException();
        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
            else
                throw new ServletException();
        }
        else
            throw new ServletException();
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The rest is a simple graphql project with kickstart implementation of graphql. I only have a couple of queries and I am trying to hit it via Altair extension. Please let me know if any more information is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now I tried to hit it with postman. It somehow is working. Any ideas what might be causing this. Also if I were to call this via an angular or react app would it still work in the current condition.